# Trying to retrieve data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve products posted by all the different users from my firestore database, I want to retrieve all posts from all users and display them on a screen (like a feed screen).

This is what the firestore data looks like:
[image: firestore screenshot]

the code that i'm using to get this data is :

```
static Future<List<Product>> getProducts(String userId) async {
    QuerySnapshot productSnapshot = await productsRef
        .document(userId)
        .collection('usersProducts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Product> products =
        productSnapshot.documents.map((doc) => Product.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return products;
  }
```

I get that i'm passing userId in there thats why i'm only getting products from one user but what is I want is all products in the database regardless of user. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a so-called **collection group query**. Such queries work based on the collection **name** instead of their path, so you can query all `usersProducts` collections with:

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('usersProducts').getDocuments()
```

To read more about this type queries, see the [blog post that announced them](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html) and their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fetch all the user products. So, directly referencing "product" node will retrieve all your data regardless of user.

```
QuerySnapshot snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection("products").getDocuments();
```

Then manage snapShot accordingly.